# drag and drop the image and update the databse also

Tags: php

`$about` contains the array in which `$about[$i]['about_bg'] = image name` and `$about[$i]['sort']= sort no` Now i can chnage the image by using drag and drop feature but i want to update the database also

How do I update the database using a ajax request?

```
<div style="margin-top: 276px;margin-left: 465px;">
    <table border="1">
        <tr >
            <td colspan="<?=count($about)?>" >drag and drop to change the image<td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
<?php       
            for ($i=0; $i<count($about) ; $i++)  {
               echo "<td>".$about[$i]['sort']."</td>";
}?> 
        </tr>
        <tr class="sortable" >
<?php       
            for ($ii=1,$i=0; $i<count($about) ; $i++)  {
                 echo "<td><img src='../img/cms/".$about[$i]['about_bg']."' title='Drag and drop the image ' height='100' width='100'></td>";
} ?>
        </tr>
       </table> 
      </div>

 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable();
    $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
  change: function() {
    $.ajax({
      //do your call
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: but how will I know which image is change ?

Comment: but how will I know which image is change ?